# vuejs data binding on img src attribute give 404 error

Tags: html, image, vue.js, data-binding

I tried to bind the img src attribute to a variable for the path of the image, and it didn't work. But if I copied and pasted the the same path in, then it works. Where did I get things wrong?

The error message: http://localhost:8080/@/assets/result-images/Soya-bean.jpg 404 (Not Found)

```
<template>
  <img :src= "imgSrc" alt="No image available"/>      //This doesn't work
  <img src= "@/assets/result-images/Soya-bean.jpg" alt="No image available"/>  //This works
</template>

<script>
import {ref} from 'vue'
export default {
  setup(){
    const imgSrc = ref()
    imgSrc.value = "@/assets/result-images/Soya-bean.jpg"
    return{imgSrc}
  }
}
</script>
```

[What it looks like on the browser](https://i.stack.imgur.com/A6sFK.png)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```js
imgSrc.value = require("@/assets/result-images/Soya-bean.jpg");
```

should do it.

Documentation [here](https://vue-loader.vuejs.org/guide/asset-url.html).

Comment: So, i should use require() everytime when i want to bind the src html attribute?

Comment: @minas, yes, that's correct. This is because the files are provided from different places while serving versus the deployed build. `vue-loader` does a lot of work behind the scenes, but you need to use `require()`.